# setValue:forKey with struct

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a question about the `setValue:forKey` method on (for example) a `UIView`.

I have the following code:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
let margins = label.valueForKey("layoutMargins")
```

In the debugger the type of `margins` is `(AnyObject?)` with the value `Some`.

If I use the variable `margins` to set the value on a `UIView`, this works as expected:

```
let label2 = UILabel()
label2.setValue(margins, forKey: "layoutMargins")
```

But if I try to set a UIEdgeInsets struct directly using the `setValue:forKey` method, this of course doesn't work, because it expects an `AnyObject` and not a struct.

```
label2.setValue(UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5), forKey: "layoutMargins")
```

Is it possible for me to wrap this `UIEdgeInsets` in *something* or cast it to something to be able to set the value using that `setValue` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `UIEdgeInsets` with `NSValue`. iOS already provides the necessary support via [`+[NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithUIEdgeInsets:), so the solution should look like this:

```
label2.setValue(NSValue(UIEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)), forKey: "layoutMargins")
```